# Elasticsearch - clearing the context of scroll id problem

Tags: elasticsearch

I am observing some warnings for clearing the context of scroll id, where to check the possible issue?

These kind errors are quite often generated in logs.

I am wondering if this is a real problem or this need to be forgotten but it is hard to read logs with such a "spam"

```
`2023-10-18T15:10:45,902 | WARN  | pool-61-thread-10 | elasticsearch-proxy              | 65 - elasticsearch-proxy - 5.0.0 | Problem occurred when clearing the context of scroll id : FGluY2x1ZGVfY29udGV4dF91dWlkDnF1ZXJ5VGhlbkZldGNoAA==
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStatusException: Unable to parse response body
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseResponseException(RestHighLevelClient.java:2464) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2184) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2137) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:2105) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.clearScroll(RestHighLevelClient.java:1559) ~[?:?]
        at common.libraries.elasticsearch.proxy.api.search.AbstractSearchService.clearContext(AbstractSearchService.java:238) ~[?:?]
        at common.libraries.elasticsearch.proxy.api.search.AbstractSearchService.clearContextSafely(AbstractSearchService.java:228) ~[?:?]
        at common.libraries.elasticsearch.proxy.api.search.AbstractSearchService.searchAndScroll(AbstractSearchService.java:120) ~[?:?]
        at common.libraries.elasticsearch.proxy.api.search.MapSearchService.lambda$search$6(MapSearchService.java:171) ~[?:?]
        at common.libraries.elasticsearch.proxy.api.ElasticsearchGateway.evalSafely(ElasticsearchGateway.java:80) ~[?:?]
        at common.libraries.elasticsearch.proxy.api.ElasticsearchServiceExecutor.evalSafely(ElasticsearchServiceExecutor.java:34) ~[?:?]
        at common.libraries.elasticsearch.proxy.api.search.MapSearchService.search(MapSearchService.java:169) ~[?:?]
        at common.libraries.elasticsearch.proxy.api.search.MapSearchService.search(MapSearchService.java:132) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
        Suppressed: org.elasticsearch.common.ParsingException: Failed to parse object: expecting field with name [error] but found [succeeded]
                at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentParserUtils.ensureFieldName(XContentParserUtils.java:43) ~[?:?]
                at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.failureFromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:587) ~[?:?]
                at org.elasticsearch.rest.BytesRestResponse.errorFromXContent(BytesRestResponse.java:170) ~[?:?]
                at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:2484) ~[?:?]
                at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseResponseException(RestHighLevelClient.java:2461) ~[?:?]
                at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2184) ~[?:?]
                at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2137) ~[?:?]
                at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:2105) ~[?:?]
                at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.clearScroll(RestHighLevelClient.java:1559) ~[?:?]
                at common.libraries.elasticsearch.proxy.api.search.AbstractSearchService.clearContext(AbstractSearchService.java:238) ~[?:?]
                at common.libraries.elasticsearch.proxy.api.search.AbstractSearchService.clearContextSafely(AbstractSearchService.java:228) ~[?:?]
                at common.libraries.elasticsearch.proxy.api.search.AbstractSearchService.searchAndScroll(AbstractSearchService.java:120) ~[?:?]
                at common.libraries.elasticsearch.proxy.api.search.MapSearchService.lambda$search$6(MapSearchService.java:171) ~[?:?]
                at common.libraries.elasticsearch.proxy.api.ElasticsearchGateway.evalSafely(ElasticsearchGateway.java:80) ~[?:?]
                at common.libraries.elasticsearch.proxy.api.ElasticsearchServiceExecutor.evalSafely(ElasticsearchServiceExecutor.java:34) ~[?:?]
                at common.libraries.elasticsearch.proxy.api.search.MapSearchService.search(MapSearchService.java:169) ~[?:?]
                at common.libraries.elasticsearch.proxy.api.search.MapSearchService.search(MapSearchService.java:132) ~[?:?]
                at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[?:?]
                at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[?:?]
                at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[?:?]
                at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655) ~[?:?]
                at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[?:?]
                at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[?:?]
                at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[?:?]
                at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[?:?]
                at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:?]
                at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497) ~[?:?]
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [DELETE], host [https://localhost:9200], URI [/_search/scroll], status line [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found]
{"succeeded":true,"num_freed":0}
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.convertResponse(RestClient.java:347) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:313) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:288) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performClientRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2699) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2171) ~[?:?]
        ... 39 more
```

`

I've checked logs but didnot find anything interesting.

Answer (score 0):

First off, those are not errors, but warnings.

You're trying to clear a scroll context (which is a good practice!), but judging by the response you get

```
{"succeeded":true,"num_freed":0}
```

The reason is because the context doesn't exist anymore, hence your DELETE request gets a 404, which the client interprets as an error situation. So it tries to parse the JSON response and find an `error` field, but there isn't any, since it's not an error per se.

```
expecting field with name [error] but found [succeeded]
```

That exception is suppressed and [wrapped within an `ElasticsearchStatusException`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/7.17/client/rest-high-level/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/client/RestHighLevelClient.java#L2444-L2469) which you can catch and ignore.

Moreover, the RestHighLevelClient [has been deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/migrate-hlrc.html) in 7.16 so you should migrate to the new Java API Client.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I am not responsible for a code that generate these warnings but operate the platform intself. Are there any possibilities to "catch and ignore" as you said in the Kibana (using Dev Tools) or in the Elasticsearch configuration?

Comment: "catch and ignore" would obviously be done at the application code level. Are you in control of the ingestion of those logs? What kind of log forwarder are you using? Filebeat, Logstash, Fluentd, ??